# How to display one animation for multiple images in vuforia & unity?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, animation, vuforia

I want to display 1 particular animation for the same image of a different kind. For example, I want to display a animation for alphabet **'A'**. But the alphabet(A) can be in many different fonts like one in **Century Gothic** and other is in **Century Schoolbook**. No matter what the font is if it's an **'A'** then just show that particular animation. It can be done by putting every font in the vuforia library but that would be very inefficient. Can I implement OCR here like first I check it's actually an **A** or not then trigger that particular animation for it? Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: I did not test this but Vuforia had a [Text recognition](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Text-Recognition-Guide) feature which was depreceated after Vuforia 7. You can try to use older version of Vuforia to use this feature if possible.

Comment: I already tried that...but that's not what I'm looking for